# CSS background image - too short

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the background image in the first page ends up being shorter than in the second.  I have only reduced the height of the #showcase div, by way of having shorter content in it.

```css
 body {
    background:url(../../../_images/bg_body.jpg) no-repeat center top #000;
    color:#716255;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family: Georgia;
 }

 #showcase{
    background:url(../../../_images/bg_showcase.png) no-repeat;
    width:970px;
    margin:7px -13px 0 -13px;
    padding:12px 26px 54px 30px;
    position:relative;
 }
```

Comment: Please try to abstract your problem down into small sections of reproducible code instead of providing a link to your own web page with tons of code. **See also**: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033).

Comment: You should put this in a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I will create a demo in the future rather then posting a URL to the live code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```css
#container {
    margin: -256px 0 0 0;
}
```